# Asp.net MVC customize account controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I had made my Project in MVC Templet , in frist i have change authorization  to individual user accounts , so it generated AspUser and AspRloe etc in my database , now i want to add Rloes and customize account controller to make the End-User to add roles to new user in Register , *How it will be ?*

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: i add roles in SQl and show pages only to Admin Users , i had to try to add role 
var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName , Roles=model. };
but the model don't show properties of AspRole table

Comment: any help .. friend ?